# C# Print 2D array prints split

Tags: c#, printing, multidimensional-array

I'm essentially trying to do the Game Of Life.  All seems well, for the most part it works as I want.  But for some reason when I go to print it out and have it play, it prints two incomplete parts of the array side by side.  Half of the cells, about every other, on on the right, the other half are on the left.  I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, I've used similar methods to print 2d arrays before with no trouble, so this is really baffling me.  Code below.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GameOfLife myGame = new GameOfLife();
        myGame.Start();
    }
}
class GameOfLife
{
    private int[,] grid = {
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};

    private int[,] tempGrid;

    public GameOfLife()
    {
        tempGrid = new int[grid.GetLength(0), grid.GetLength(1)];
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        Setup();

        do
        {
            Thread.Sleep(30);
            UpdateGrid();
            CopyTempGridToGrid();
            PrintGrid();
        } while (!Console.KeyAvailable);

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    private void UpdateGrid()
    {
        for(int r = 0; r < grid.GetLength(0); r++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c < grid.GetLength(1); c++)
            {
                tempGrid[r, c] = UpdateCell(r, c);
            }
        }
    }

    private void CopyTempGridToGrid()
    {
        Array.Copy(tempGrid, grid, tempGrid.Length);
    }

    private void PrintGrid()
    {
        Console.CursorTop = 2;

        for (int r = 0; r < grid.GetLength(0); r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < grid.GetLength(1); c++)
            {
                if (grid[r, c] == 0)
                {
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                    Console.Write(".");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                    Console.Write(".");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private int GetNeighbors(int row, int col)
    {
        int neighbors = 0;
        try
        {
            if (grid[row - 1, col - 1] == 1)
                neighbors++;
            if (grid[row - 1, col] == 1)
                neighbors++;
            if (grid[row - 1, col + 1] == 1)
                neighbors++;
            if (grid[row, col - 1] == 1)
                neighbors++;
            if (grid[row, col + 1] == 1)
                neighbors++;
            if (grid[row + 1, col - 1] == 1)
                neighbors++;
            if (grid[row + 1, col] == 1)
                neighbors++;
            if (grid[row + 1, col + 1] == 1)
                neighbors++;
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfRangeException) { }
        return neighbors;
    }

    private int UpdateCell(int row, int col)
    {
        int n = GetNeighbors(row, col);

        if (n <= 1)
            return 0;
        if (n == 2)
            return grid[row, col];
        if (n == 3)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    private void Setup()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.CursorVisible = false;
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop");
        PrintGrid();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hard coding a sparse array is wrong. I would code insertion of simple primitives (right now you only have 4 lines anyway), initialize blank array, then do 4 insert lines (x, y, length). You'll thank yourself when you want to research how different [game of life primitives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway's_Game_of_Life#Examples_of_patterns) live over time.

Comment: yeah for sure, my plan was to do that differently but I wanted to sort out the other problem first.  Do you think it is the root of the array printing split side by side?

Comment: `root of the array printing split side by side?` <-- I don't understand your question. Please elaborate more.

Comment: Andiih answered the question below.  I just wanted to know if you thought your earlier suggestion was the cause of my original question.

Comment: My suggestion was the first one that came in mind. I wasn't sure if this was your problem, that's why I posted it as a comment. Generally, reducing your code helps isolate the problem, so that's why I thought you may find it helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the loops within  PrintGrid() have inner and an outer nested loops, they are not outputting a newline after each row. I'd try a Console.Writeln("") between the inner and outer loops.